# Tapping on segmentedControl gives unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I don't know why my segmentedControl isn't working. If I press on it, I get the error

> [AddDetailViewController segmentedControlIndexChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71e0ad0
>   2012-11-05 16:25:51.380 proiect_caini[5903:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AddDetailViewController segmentedControlIndexChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71e0ad0'

I want when I click on the segmentedControl that is located in a cell of a table to get selected and to save that, so that I can display it.

Another problem is that I can't locate this on the right side of the cell.

Here is my code:

This code is located in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, when I create the cell

```
 case 8:{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Parinti";
        //inputField.text = 
        lblParinti.text = dog?dog.parinti:@"";

        segmentedControl1 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems: segmentItems];
 //            segmentedControl1.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
 //            segmentedControl1.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

        [segmentedControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [cell addSubview:lblParinti];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl1];
        break;}
```

Here is the event that is triggered:

```
  -(void) segmentedControlIndexChanged{

    // reload data based on the new index

    if (segmentedControl1.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        dog.parinti = @"Da";
    } else if (segmentedControl1.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        dog.parinti = @"Nu";
    }
    //dog.parinti = [segmentedControl1 titleForSegmentAtIndex:segmentedControl1.selectedSegmentIndex];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you in any way please check my answer as accepted as this will encourage people to answer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from

`[segmentedControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

to

`[segmentedControl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

If you use `@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:)` you are saying that your method has an argument (which it doesn't).